# How to handle retrying attempt to delete file in Apache Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I do have route that polls from a folder called cache and persist them to database. If database connection fails, the file is redirected to the same cache folder. On second retry attempt on polling, again if database connection fails, these files are not stored under cache folder but deleted.

DEBUG FileUtil                       - Retrying attempt 0 to delete file: D:\KAMAL\1464750264460-0-44.camelLock
DEBUG FileUtil                       - Tried 1 to delete file: \KAMAL\1464750264460-0-44.camelLock with result: true

Comment: The .camelLock is a file that Camel creates to indicate it has a lock on the file. Its NOT the actual file.